# Using an EE date tag with formatting in php code

Tags: php, tags, date, calendar

I'm using some php code (output parsing) in a template, between {exp:channel:calendar} tags. I have a line assigning the value of a custom date field to the php variable %endDate. Then, I need to test if {date} is equal to this $endDate variable. But if I use {date} alone it just takes the string "{date}" instead of its actual value, and I think that's because that tag requires a format parameter, so now I'm tryng this:

if ("{date format="%U"}" == $endDate)

but, obviously, this gives me a php syntax error and just screws up half of the template... Any idea what syntax I should use to do this?

Comment: After some further experimentation, I realized the whole {date format="%U"} doesn't work, even outside of PHP. Just trying to display its value in plain simple HTML fails. Has anyone else encountered any problems with the {date} variable in {exp:channel:calendar} tags??

Comment: Something just hit me... this client's site is on EE 2.5.2... Did that variable exist back then? I can't seem to find EE's documentation for older versions...

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
{title}<br />
{entry_date format="%U"}<br />
<?php
$compare_date ="1123581363";
echo $compare_date." - compare date<br />";
$e_date = {entry_date format="%U"};
echo $e_date." - E date<br />";   
if ($compare_date > {entry_date format="%U"}) {echo "I am Greater than";} else {echo "I am Less than";}
?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Template set to php on output.

Comment: If your looking for the NOW date and time use : 
{current_time format="%U"} instead of {date format="%U"}

Comment: I'm not trying to format the entry date or current date in a channel entry tag, I'm trying to format the date variable in a calendar tag (i.e. this date: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/calendar.html#date)
And {date format="%U"} doesn't work at all so I'm guessing this variable wasn't available in EE 2.5.2., so I found another way to do what I wanted to without using the variable. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code `if ("{date format="%U"}" == $endDate)` isn't correct and you couldn't compare the a PHP variable with EE variable with EE's IF condition due to parsing stage.

The variable {date format="%U"} will work if you are have "date" as Date type field and it will return seconds since the epoch.

You can try the condition code like: `if ("{date format="%U"}" == "<?php echo $endDate; ?>)` make sure the "PHP Parsing Stage" is selected as "Input". But I am not sure if it would work properly for you as you are putting the condition within channel entry tag and where assign the value for PHP variable $endDate.

Comment: I'm not using EE's if condition. This is a PHP line. It's a PHP if condition. And it's not in a channel entry tag, it's in a calendar tag, and date is a variable available for calendar tags, not a field.